# Error when moving VBulletin mysql database to new server via phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, vbulletin

I'm trying to move vbulletin forum from bluehost server to webhosting bad. I first downloaded the vb folder from the older server and uploaded it back to the new server.

For the database, I used phpmyadmin in bluehost.com to export my database and when I try to imprt it back in the new server I get this error :

---

SQL query:

```
DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> <title>phpMyAdmin  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="phpmyadmin.css.php?server=1&amp;token=5739e47e2a94b96da71dc4213f69b5a4&amp;js_frame=right&amp;nocache=5344073683" /> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" /> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css" /> <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" /> <script src="./js/cross_framing_protection.js?ts=1332953438" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="./js/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js?ts=1332953[...]

MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w' at line 1
```

---

Can any one please guide me to the solution ?
The bluehost phpmyadmin version is 3.4.10.2 and the webhostingpad is 3.4.10.1 is this the reason of the problem ? if yes, what is the solution ??

Answer (score 0):

So you have downloaded an export from your old host? What format did you download this as? Just SQL or some kind of compressed version? As the first thing to do should be to identify if the problem is with the host you're uploading to or the one you're taking the data from. I'd suggest opening the exported file locally and seeing if it looks to be a valid SQL dump or not.

Comment: yes I downloaded an export from the old host with the default formats. I didn't make any changes and the selection was SQL no compressed or any other stuff.

Comment: Do you have access to somewhere else you can try uploading this export to? Just to be sure if it's a problem with the exported file or where you're uploading it to. Uploading it back onto your old host maybe but into a different database. As based on what you've said it sounds like an issue with phpmyadmin on your new host (but shouldn't be related to version numbers - SQL is SQL and should still be imported the same)